# How could I replace a form with already inserted text after unsuccesfull finding in database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the code in Participate.php file which has a form:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php" id="Form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtName" maxlength="20" required style="margin-bottom:20px"> 
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="txtEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnsubmit" value="Zgłoś się" />
        </form>
```

After unsucessful submit (I check if inserted mail already exist in database) and if no exist I want to refill value for form. This is the input.php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['txtName']; 
$mail = $_POST['txtEmail']; 
$description = $_POST['txtDescription'];
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=4*****3;dbname=3*****b", "3***b", "****");
$connect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

$q=$connect->prepare("SELECT mail FROM konkurs WHERE mail LIKE (?)");
$q->bindValue(1, $mail);
$q->execute();
$row_cnt = $q->rowCount();
    if($row_cnt == 0){
        $query = $connect->prepare("insert into konkurs(name,mail,description)
        values(?, ?, ?)");
        $query->bindValue(1, $name);
        $query->bindValue(2, $mail);
        $query->bindValue(3, $description);
        try {
            $query->execute();
            echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Sent.');
            window.location.href='index.html';
            </script>");
            exit;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
            } 
    } else {
        echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('This mail already exist.');
            window.location.href='Participate.php';
            document.getElementById('txtName').value = 'nothing';
            </script>");
        }

?>
```

The thing is it's redirecting to Participate.php after unsuccesfull sumbition. But it doesn't refill the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must change your HTML to include the `id` attribute, for example:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php" id="Form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" name="txtName" maxlength="20" required style="margin-bottom:20px"> 
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnsubmit" value="Zgłoś się" />
</form>
```

Then, you **must** move your logic to the same file as the form container (here `Participate.php`), and remove the redirection for failures. Otherwise, you'll get no visible results, as the redirection would prevent further JavaScript code from running.

```
// Updated to prevent syntax errors with multiline strings
echo "<script>"
     . "window.alert('This mail already exist.');"
     . "document.getElementById('txtName').value = 'nothing';"
     . "</script>";
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The thing is it's redirecting to Participate.php and form is empty.

Comment: You can't change anything on the `Participate.php` page while being in the `input.php` page, even if you didn't redirect. If you want to modify the input in the `Participate.php` file, your JavaScript **must** be in the same file.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can pass this values?

Comment: Through URL query parameters, you can pass values to the redirected page; they would be accessed through `$_GET['param']` in PHP. But it's not really a common and safe way to achieve this.